# How to format a string using variables instead of numbers within curly braces?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string-formatting

I'm using Python 3.7 and I have stored a value inside a variable. This variable holds the value of padding which I want to use within curly braces for string formatting. The code explains what I am trying to do.

```
def print_formatted(number):
    for i in range(1, number + 1):
        binum = bin(i).replace('0b', '')
        ocnum = oct(i).replace('0o', '')
        hexnum = hex(i).replace('0x', '')

        length = len(bin(number).replace('0b', ''))
        print('{0:>length} {1:>length} {2:>length} {3:>length}'.format(i, ocnum, hexnum, binum)) # Error here
```

This is the code that I have been trying to run. What I am trying to do is to right align the numbers by padding it by the value of the length of the last binary number.

> ValueError: Invalid format specifier

This is the error I get. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use f-strings and also format specifiers to avoid use of the `hex`, `oct` and `bin` builtins and then string slicing and use `int.bit_length()` instead of taking the length of the binary string, eg:

```
def print_formatted(number):
    # get number of bits required to store number
    w = number.bit_length()
    for n in range(1, number + 1):
        # print each number as decimal, then octal, then hex, then binary with padding
        print(f'{n:>{w}} {n:>{w}o} {n:>{w}x} {n:>{w}b}')
```

Running `print_formatted(20)` will give you:

```
    1     1     1     1
    2     2     2    10
    3     3     3    11
    4     4     4   100
    5     5     5   101
    6     6     6   110
    7     7     7   111
    8    10     8  1000
    9    11     9  1001
   10    12     a  1010
   11    13     b  1011
   12    14     c  1100
   13    15     d  1101
   14    16     e  1110
   15    17     f  1111
   16    20    10 10000
   17    21    11 10001
   18    22    12 10010
   19    23    13 10011
   20    24    14 10100
```

Answer (score 2):

You must first incorporate the value of the variable `length` into your format string and, strangely, using `.format()` is the best way to do it.

Change the following line

```
print('{0:>length} {1:>length} {2:>length} {3:>length}'.format(i, ocnum, hexnum, binum))
```

to

```
print('{{0:>{length}}} {{1:>{length}}} {{2:>{length}}} {{3:>{length}}}'.format(length=length).format(i, ocnum, hexnum, binum))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `f-strings`.

```
def print_formatted(number):
    length = len(bin(number)) - 2
    for i in range(1, number + 1):
        ocnum = oct(i)[2:]
        hexnum = hex(i)[2:]
        binum = bin(i)[2:]
        print(' '.join(f'{n:>{length}}' for n in (i, ocnum, hexnum, binum)))

>>> print_formatted(20)
    1     1     1     1
    2     2     2    10
    3     3     3    11
    4     4     4   100
    5     5     5   101
    6     6     6   110
    7     7     7   111
    8    10     8  1000
    9    11     9  1001
   10    12     a  1010
   11    13     b  1011
   12    14     c  1100
   13    15     d  1101
   14    16     e  1110
   15    17     f  1111
   16    20    10 10000
   17    21    11 10001
   18    22    12 10010
   19    23    13 10011
   20    24    14 10100
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually do it in two steps, creating a format string first. It works by escaping the braces - `{{`,`}}` - that need to remain in the format string.

```
>>> length = 4
>>> f'{{:>{length}}} {{:>{length}}} {{:>{length}}} {{:>{length}}}'
'{:>4} {:>4} {:>4} {:>4}'
>>> 


fmt = f'{{:>{length}}} {{:>{length}}} {{:>{length}}} {{:>{length}}}'
print(fmt.format(i, ocnum, hexnum, binum))
```